# org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button click from code

Tags: java, swt

I am trying to click Button from code. I am tying to do the following:

```
class MyMouseAdapter extends MouseAdapter
{
    public void mouseDown(MouseEvent evt) 
    {
       System.out.println("Working!!!!");
    }
}
Button button = new Button();
button.addMouseListener(new MyMouseAdapter());
```

now I want to run the mouseDown method from code could you tell me how to do it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can do this:

```
button.notifyListeners( SWT.MouseDown, null );
```

Where `null` is an `Event`. Remember that this is the `Event` received by your listener.

Comment: This is not completely correct as it does not completely emulate a button press. I understand that this is not what you're asking for, but, the code above only give you a `MouseDown`, but no `MouseUp`, `Selection`, `MouseEnter`, `FocusIn`, etc...

Comment: I know, but as he wanted to "run the mouseDown method from code", that did the trick.  :o)

Answer (score 3):

If you need all the listeners to be notified then you can try the below code,

```
yourbutton.notifyListeners(SWT.Selection, new Event());
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the correct behavior from a mouse press on a button, you need to simulate the `MouseDown` and `MouseUp` using `Display.post(...)` - there are no other way to get the correct architecture dependent behavior.

You can find plenty of code around for this - including [Testing a Plug-in - User Interface Testing](http://tonnymadsen.blogspot.dk/2011/04/testing-plug-in-user-interface-testing.html).

**UPDATED** the link

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is the kind of solution you are looking for but why not keeping a  local variable of your MyMouseAdapter instance and call the mouseDown method directly on it?
Something like the following snippet:

```
class MyMouseAdapter extends MouseAdapter
{
    public void mouseDown(MouseEvent evt) 
    {
       System.out.println("Working!!!!");
    }
}
MyMouseAdapter adapter = new MyMouseAdapter();
Button button = new Button();
button.addMouseListener(adapter);

//Somehow create a new MouseEvent then call the following:
adapter.mouseDown(yourNewEvent);
```

Comment: I want to take the adapter from button

Comment: You can retrieve it directly from button, but I think Mario's solution will match your needs

Answer (score 0):

My answer is to essentially simulate the mouse click event.  There is lots of examples out there so if my links don't work for you do a quick search.  the answer depends on the libraries you are importing.

You could use the java.awt.Robot to simulate a programmic button press like at the following link.
http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/java.awt/RobotmousePressintbuttons.htm

Or you if you are using SWT you could use Display.post(Event e) like at the following:
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/SWT-JFace-Eclipse/UIAutomationfortestingtoolssnippetpostmouseevents.htm

Either of these routes require coordinates to be supplied for the click event and potentially a reference to the object being clicked, so it would require said objects finding the control (in this instance the button you are trying to click) so that it can be clicked.

If you are using swing just do button.doClick().