# How to create a click event search button in Eclipse using?

Tags: eclipse, sqlite

How to create a click event search button in Eclipse?? Can someone help me. This is the code im working with.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);

      listContent1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lFoodlist1);

      mySQLiteAdapter = new SQLiteAdapter(this);
      mySQLiteAdapter.openToRead();

      Cursor cursor = mySQLiteAdapter.queueAll();

      startManagingCursor(cursor);

      String[] from = new String[]{SQLiteAdapter.KEY_FOODNAME,SQLiteAdapter.KEY_CALORIES};
      int[] to = new int[]{R.id.tv1, R.id.tv2};

      SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter =
      new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row, cursor, from, to);

      listContent1.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);
      //listContent.setOnItemClickListener(listContentOnItemClickListener);*/

  }
```

Comment: You want a button that searches click events?  What?

Comment: This might help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6595663/org-eclipse-swt-widgets-button-click-from-code.

Comment: see this link https://vaadin.com/tutorial/-/chapter/interaction.search.html

Comment: I've created a database. Then i want to search only the name of what i've inputed in the txtbox.

Comment: What kind of database? It sounds like you will need to 1) Connect your app to the DB 2) Have a DB query that takes into account the textbox values 3) The button executes the query and returns the data in some way. People are downvoting your question since it is vague :(. It may get closed unless you provide some sample code or elaborate on your issue a little more.

Comment: The above code works and you simple want it to execute on a button click?

Comment: I want o create a search button, where it will display what i've input in the edit text. It will display the food that in database.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5456854/java-swing-how-to-show-text-after-button-is-clicked You can become familiar with Swing and use something like this. You would put the code you want executed in the actionlistener section.

Comment: The one that i input in the search bar is from the database, like the ordinary search button in every sites. I have a little idea on how to do this, based on what i read, click event is the simplest way. But i dont know how.

Answer (score 0):

This code was taken from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5456854/java-swing-how-to-show-text-after-button-is-clicked) and was modified/commented to help the poseter with his scenario.

You can implement [swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/swing/reference.html) to help with the GUI aspect of your application. Others may prefer [AWT](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/package-summary.html)

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class myTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //This will create the JFrame/JPanel/JButton
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JButton button1 = new JButton();

        //Add your panel and button and make them visable
        frame.add(panel);
        panel.add(button1);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        //This adds the actionListener to the Button
        button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            //When the button is clicked this action will be performed
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                //Add your code here.
            }
        });

    }

}
```